# This is a bug in Date class or i mistake (Java/android)

Tags: java, android, date

i write this code

```
Date xx2 = new Date(2017,3,31);
Date xx3 = new Date(2017,4,1);

Assistance.print("--> y:"+xx2.getYear()+"  m:"+xx2.getMonth()+" d:"+xx2.getDate());
Assistance.print("--> y:"+xx3.getYear()+"  m:"+xx3.getMonth()+" d:"+xx3.getDate());
```

but i get same result !!!

Result:

--> y: 2017  m:4   d:1

--> y: 2017  m:4   d:1

What?

Comment: Months in java.util.Date start from 0, so 4 ias actually May

Comment: January is 0, February is 1, March is 2, April is 3, may is 4... But there are constants for this

Comment: It's not a bug, but the worst design choice ever (make January be zero)

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This issue has been covered many many many times already.

Comment: It's never the API, it's always the programmer. (Well, nearly. One should never speak in absolutes.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the javadoc of constructor 
[`Date(int year, int month, int day)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(int,%20int,%20int))
carefully, especially

> `month` - the month between 0-11

Hence, `new Date(2017,3,31)` is April 31,
and `new Date(2017,4,1)` is May 01, which is actually the same day (because April has 30 days only).

Answer (score 0):

Months are 0 indexed. January == 0, so Date `xx2` is April 31st. There is no such date on the calendar. The 31st day from the start of April is May 1st. That is why both dates are the same.